# User's location on google map using GPS

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I'm trying to mark app user's location right after turning on the app. But, it marks wrong and same location every time. Log also cannot catch latitude and longitude.

Here is manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />


<permission android:name="com.myhouse.woohyun.tripal2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permissions.READ_GSERVICES" />


<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />


    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

}

This is my only activity.
I have tried to change several times. But still doesn't work.
Others things work but latitude and longitude.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private LocationListener locationListener;
double latitude;
double longitude;
private String TAG;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);




    locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(latitude));
            Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(longitude));

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 5000, 0, locationListener);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    LatLng mylocation = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(mylocation).title("Here"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mylocation, 13.0f));
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}
```

}

Comment: is your onLocationChanged gets called or not ?

Comment: The log doesn't show anything. So, it doesnt get called I think

Comment: follow these tutorial http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html

Comment: @jiteshmohite Still doesn't work

Comment: what error you are getting

Comment: @jiteshmohite I solved :) moved addMarker, moveCamera to onLocationChanged and it works :) anyways thanks dude!